# Part of input is hidden when editing QListWidget items in and RTL language

Tags: python, right-to-left, pyside2, hebrew, qlistwidget

The UI must be in our native language which is Hebrew. Hebrew is a "Right to Left" (RTL) language, so everything must be displayed from right to left.

I figured out that it's actually simple to display Hebrew text in PySide2 since python accepts non English strings, and there is function: `app.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)` which sets the entire layout to RTL which solves my issue.

However, I faced a weird problem which probably happens because of the rtl ui (I didn't notice the problem in default left to right layout).

I am using a `QListWidget` to display the students names in a list (in the future, the users will be able to add/remove students. Now the list displays dummy data). All items are editable, so the user can change the student's names.

The weird thing is that when I edit a short name (2 or 3 letters) the input is cut off and only shown again when editing is done. The screenshots should make it more clear:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, when I double click the name "דן" to change it, the name gets cut off. When I start typing to change the name, the beginning of the new input "אריאל" is still cut off. Only when I press enter to finish editing, The name is displayed correctly again.

I know that this problem happens because of the RTL display because when I comment that out, everything works normally both for Hebrew and English input.

Do you have any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?
Here's the full code:

school_system_manager.py

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QAction,
    QApplication,
    QDockWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QStatusBar,
    QWidget,
)

from panels import StudentsPanel


class SchoolSystemManager(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("מנהל מערכת שעות")

        # region Actions
        exit_action = QAction("&יציאה", self)
        exit_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Quit)
        exit_action.setStatusTip("כיבוי מנהל מערכת השעות")
        exit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        # endregion

        # region Docking
        dock = QDockWidget("רשימת התלמידים", self)
        student_list = StudentsPanel(dock)
        student_list.addItems(("דניאל", "שי", "שירה", "דן", "שרון", "עדן"))
        dock.setWidget(student_list)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock)
        # endregion

        # region Menus and status bar
        menu = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menu.addMenu("&קובץ")
        file_menu.addAction(exit_action)

        view_menu = menu.addMenu("&תצוגה")
        view_menu.addAction(dock.toggleViewAction())

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(self))
        # endregion

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)  # Comment out for left to right display
    school_system_manager = SchoolSystemManager()
    school_system_manager.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

panels.py

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem


class StudentsPanel(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, min_width=200):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumWidth(min_width)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)

    def addItem(self, item):
        item = QListWidgetItem(item, self)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)

    def addItems(self, items):
        for item in items:
            item = QListWidgetItem(item, self)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setting the role of Qt.TextAlignmentRole to Qt.AlignRight
This may help you solve this

Comment: Didn't work. It actually caused the text to align to the left. According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum), when the direction of the app is set to `Qt::RightToLeft`, `Qt::AlignLeft` refers to the right edge and `Qt::AlignRight` to the left edge. So, it didn't solve my issue. The only alignment that solves it is `Qt::AlignHCenter`, but I think it doesn't look nice if the text is centered.